# Add additional upload field to Custom Header page

Tags: custom-header

I use the custom header feature for my theme and I’d like to add an additional upload field to the Custom Header page in the backend (page=custom-header) for a custom logo upload.

I found [this](https://illuminatikarate.com/blog/add-your-own-options-to-wordpress-custom-header-image-screen/) but the custom options aren’t saved.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 5):

I just did something similar recently. Instead of putting it on the Custom Header page, you should be adding things to the Theme Customizer (new in 3.4). It's just as easy and is a more standard way of adding new theme options.

In fact, just by having added the Custom Header, the Theme Customizer should be active on your theme already. When you click Customize, you should see the header options in there. To add a new section that allows custom logo upload, try something like this:

```
add_action( 'customize_register', 'themename_customize_register' );
function themename_customize_register($wp_customize) {

    $wp_customize->add_section( 'ignite_custom_logo', array(
        'title'          => 'Logo',
        'description'    => 'Display a custom logo?',
        'priority'       => 25,
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'custom_logo', array(
        'default'        => '',
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'custom_logo', array(
        'label'   => 'Custom logo',
        'section' => 'ignite_custom_logo',
        'settings'   => 'custom_logo',
    ) ) );
}
```

That code will give you a new box in the Theme Customizer, like so:

[image: Theme Customizer logo upload]

Comment: PS: Otto has a great write-up about using the Theme Customizer: http://ottopress.com/2012/how-to-leverage-the-theme-customizer-in-your-own-themes/

Comment: Glad it worked! Mind picked it as the correct answer? (to help others find it)

Comment: Thank you so much.. after I add this code I see the field to upload in `customizer` also I am ablo to upload the image. Anyhow how to print this anywhere we want it? `echo get_header_image();` prints empty

Comment: You need to wrap it in an img tag:

`<img src="<?php echo( get_header_image() ); ?>" alt="<?php echo( get_bloginfo( 'title' ) ); ?>" />`

Answer (score 0):

how you think  get_header_image() will work? i can not see anything u write on function.php like get_header_image(); so how it should print the image?

SO please try it will work echo get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' );